# How to customize what details customers get to review before making payment?

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal

I am using Wordpress as the CMS for my site. I am using an ecommerce plug in called WP E Commerce and using Paypal Express Checkout. So basically, you add/drop an item in the cart on my site, go to the checkout page, you enter your contact/billing details and then you go to Paypal to pay. You are then taken back to my site to review your order details. The order details lists the total amount and the shipping address.

I want to change that to the product name, total amount and billing address. There is a file in my Wordpress, plugins/WP E Commerce directory that is calling this info. I want to know how to call the product name info to be displayed in the review order details area?

Comment: So what happens if someone purchases 2 products?

Comment: Well for now I want to know how to pass that info to paypal and pass it back, let's assume there is only 1 product in the whole site? I want that to be displayed in the customer order review details.

Comment: Well, I'm not really familiar with the application, though it's probably an easy fix - BUT I would be very surprised if they actually sent that data to PayPal. It would be more likely that they sent the order id, customer info and total amount and then retrieved any other info from the database when paypal returned a success and the order is changed to paid. ALSO, you will probly find that the product name is kept in a different table then the invoices. So you will need to make a seperate SQL call with LIMIT 1 to make sure you get 1 product. If you return some code, I'm more than happy to help

Comment: How may I connect with you. where are you located? I don't mind paying you for a few hours of work. Are you on Skype or do you have an e-mail whereby we can chat more efficiently or must we discuss all particulars openly on here?

Comment: I think I lost that chat box.